# Expressing $\cos^5(x)$ using trigonometric addition formulas

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$, and $\cos^3(x) = \frac{1}{4}(\cos(3x) + 3\cos(x))$, how can we express $\cos^5(x)$ in the same way?

Comment: I do not understand how you want to represent it. Are you sure you do not mean $\cos(5x)$?

Comment: Taking into account what you wrote, the lhs are $\cos(4x)$ and $\cos(3x)$. Please edit.

Comment: I fixed the question again. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what "the same way" really means, but in any case you can write $\cos(n x)$ in terms of a polynomial in $\cos x$ through [Chebyshev's polynomials of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). We have:
$$ \cos(nx) = T_n(\cos x), $$
where:
$$ T_0(x)=1,\quad T_1(x)=x,\quad T_{n+2}(x)=2x\, T_{n+1}(x)-T_{n}(x) $$
follow from:
$$ \cos((n+2)x)+\cos(nx) = 2\cos(x)\cos((n+1)x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $5x=2x+3x$.
$$\cos(5x)=\cos(3x+2x)$$
$$=\cos3x\cos2x-\sin3x\sin2x$$

Using the formulas you already know of $\cos(3x),\sin(3x)$, you can get $\cos^5x$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\cos^5x=\cos^3x\times\cos^2x$$

Substitue, values from the formula for $\cos 3x$ and $\cos 2x$, to get your desired result.

Yes, there does not exist a straight forward formula for $\cos^5 x$, why don't you create one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant $\cos(5x)$, we could do it a cool way using De Moivre's formula, which states
$$(e^{ix})^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx),$$ 
hence
\begin{align}
\cos(5x)+i\sin(5x)&=\left(\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\right)^5\\
&=\cos^5(x)+5i\cos^4(x)\sin(x)-10\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)\\
& \ \ \ \ -10i\cos^2(x)\sin^3(x)+5\cos(x)\sin^4(x)+i\sin^5(x) \ \ \text{by binomial expansion}.
\end{align}
We can equate the real parts now, hence
\begin{align}
\cos(5x)&=\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)+5\cos(x)\sin^4(x)\\
&=\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)(1-\cos^2(x))+5\cos(x)(1-\cos^2(x))(1-\cos^2(x))\\
&=\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)+10\cos^5(x)+5\cos(x)\left[1-2\cos^2(x)+\cos^4(x)\right]\\
&=11\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x)-10\cos^3(x)+5\cos^5(x)\\
&=16\cos^5(x)-20\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your 'in the same way' is not clear, but I guess that you might like the following :

Since one has
$$\color{blue}{\cos(5x)}=\cos^5(x)-10\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)+5\cos(x)\sin^4(x)$$
$$=\color{blue}{16\cos^5(x)-20\cos^3(x)+5\cos(x)},$$one has$$\begin{align}\color{red}{\cos^5(x)}&=\frac{1}{16}(\cos(5x)-5\cos(x)+20\cos^3(x))\\&=\frac{1}{16}(\cos(5x)-5\cos(x)+20\cdot\frac 14(\cos(3x)+3\cos(x)))\\&=\color{red}{\frac{1}{16}(\cos(5x)+5\cos(3x)+10\cos(x))}.\end{align}$$